# rabbitmq docker container .erlang.cookie is not set from RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE env variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to set up a rabbitmq cluster on with aws container service. I need the `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie` to be the same on all nodes. So for all my rabbitmq containers when they are run I pass in a `RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE` environment variable which according to documentation here https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/ should be written into `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie`.

When I inspect my running container I can see that environment variable `RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=QOKWQHQKXXTBIEAOPWKE` is present but when i `cat /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie` I get a different value `AYMNAPKRPCPJVPFYAJZX`.

As a result all rabbitmq containers have different `.erlang.cookie` and cannot form a cluster.

Why isn't the cookie from environment variable set? What could I be missing here?

I am using rabbitmq:3.6.9-alpine image.

Comment: Can you post the task definition? The relevant code is at https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/master/3.6/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh#L164-L176. I am guessing maybe you are mounting a volume at `/var/lib/rabbitmq` and maybe the `.erlang.cookie` already exists and is skipping the environment variable.

Comment: @AndyShinn this is exactly what happened. I was mounting a volume and i started rabbits without any cluster config at first. So each one created its own `.erlang.cookie`. Later when I was passing in cookie as env variable it just couldn't write it into the file.

Answer (score 3):

I run into this thread when search very similar problem, but my env var is ERLANG_COOKIE, after I changed to use RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE, it's working like a charm

Here comes my docker-compose about rabbitmq, ${HOST} will be replaced with value set in .env file which lives in the same folder as docker-compose.yml

```
rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:3-management
  ports:
    - "15672:15672"
    - "25672:25672"
    - "5672:5672"
    - "4369:4369"
  environment:
    - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='takeMyCookies'
  hostname: "${HOST}"
```

Take a look at the cookie value

```
root@prod-03:/# cat ~/.erlang.cookie
'takeMyCookies'
root@prod-03:/# cat /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
'takeMyCookies'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error until I configured the cookie value correctly and removed the '-' character from it.

Another way to set it is `RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="-setcookie cookie-value"`

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in version 3.9 of the RabbitMQ docker image where the RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE value is not being written to the /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie file in the container. The bug is identified here -> https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/pull/502.

One solution is to use some other version of the RabbitMQ docker image, such as version 3.8.

```
docker pull rabbitmq:3.8-management
```

Or, if you must use version 3.9, then you can create the .erlang.cookie file on your Docker system and use the -v or --volume option to mount the .erlang.cookie file on your Docker system to /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie in the container.

```
docker run --detach --volume /path/to/.erlang.cookie:/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie rabbitmq:management
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to chmod erlang.cookie to 600 if using the docker volume hack.

Comment: In version 3.9.12 in status it says:
"RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE env variable support is deprecated and will be REMOVED in a future version. Use the $HOME/.erlang.cookie file or the --erlang-cookie switch instead."